# Hoiw can i get y coordinates of my clicked element on the whole page?

Tags: javascript, windowlistener

I have big data on Y coordinate - there is virtual scroll and a lot of items are on the page on scroll.
When i click on the data then additional data is displayed for the clicked element.
That makes my page unfriendly for users because sometime the additional data is big - and when the additional data is collapsed sometimes scroll automatically goes down and the user needs to scroll a little bit up to see the data...

I need when the user click on the element- automatically page scrolls up or down to that clicked element on the Y coordinate

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let mainRow of tableData; let i = index;" class="card" id="mainRow-{{i}}">
   <div (click)="renderSubTable(i, mainRow, $event)">
     ... main data
   </div>

  <div *ngIf="mainRow.subTableData">
     ... additional data
  </div>

</div>
```

** what i tried**
**TS**

i tried with `offsetY`

```
  renderSubTable(numRow, mainRow, event) {
   let y = pos.offsetY;
   window.scroll(0,y);
}
```

but that takes only the Y coordinates of the viewport - not on the whole page.
PageY does not work also.

How can i resolve my issue

Comment: No, this i relative to the browser viewport...

Comment: I need absolute value...

Comment: If the given answer doesn't answer your question your question is either unclear or lacking important details.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) gives you the absolute position (relative to the document):

```js
const el = document.getElementById('el');
el.onclick = function() {
    const offset = $("#el").offset();
    window.scroll(0, offset.top);
    console.log(offset);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 1000px; background: blue; padding-top:200px">
  <div id="el" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; margin: 0 50px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a code snippet for Angular

Template

```
<div style="height: 1000px; background: blue; padding-top:200px">
  <div (click)="onClick($event)" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red; margin: 0 50px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    const offset = $(event.target).offset();
    window.scroll(0, offset.top);
    console.log(offset);
  }
}
```

You can test it on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7bxbl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I jhave a lot of nested elements - offset will give me the neares parent right ?

Comment: @sdsd According to the documentation it gives you the absolute position (relative to the document, not to the parent): _"Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document."_ You can see it in my example snippet. The red div has position (50, 200) relative to the parent but the output is the absolute position (58, 208). The parent's position is (8, 8).

Comment: I am having click event in angular - i can't combine it with jquery...

Comment: Also i have a lot of elemments in ngFor - i can't have carcoded id to search for

Comment: @sdsd Why can't you use jQuery with Angular? I've worked on multiple projects using both together. You don't need to use an id. jQuery can convert native elements into jQuery objects. An Angular click event contains the native element.

Comment: I implemented your solution with jquery now. But still when i click and scrolling goes a little bit down. So i get the position with the offest and then i use ` window.scroll(0,offset.top);` but it does not work correctly

Comment: What could be the issue ?

Comment: @sdsd On Stackoverflow you ask a specific question and get specific answers. The concept doesn't work well with discussions and follow-up questions. Your question was how to get the absolute position for HTML elements with Angular. Your question is answered. If you have another question you should ask a new question.

Comment: It is not answeered because it is not working, that is the reason i added question here

Comment: I said - it is not working. I am not asking multiply questions in one question.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell without an exact example (how your HTML is structured), but you should also take a look at:

(Doing on element's api not window api)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView